# insertion in Plist flie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I am new to iphone

I have storedGameData.plist file and under "root" dictionary under "root" dictionary I have an array named "gameProgress" and I want to insert data in this "gameProgress" array.

following is my code

```
-(void)writeDataToPhone
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"storedGameData.plist"];

    // read or create plist

    NSMutableDictionary *dict;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] ) {

        // Reading the Plist from inside the if

        //statement

        NSLog(@"dictionary existed, reading %@", plistPath);

        dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    }

   NSNumber *newNumberOfCompletedLevels = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    [dict setObject:newNumberOfCompletedLevels forKey:@"gameProgress"];

    NSLog(@"writing to %@…", plistPath);

    [dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];


NSLog(@"dictionary values are…:");

for (id key in dict) {

    NSLog(@"key=%@, value=%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);

    }
}
```

but my array is blank nothing is inserted in it

what is the problem with my code? and what should I change in my code to insert value in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working absolutely fine.
I just do,

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"storedGameData.plist"];

// read or create plist

NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath] ) {

    // Reading the Plist from inside the if

    //statement

    NSLog(@"dictionary existed, reading %@", plistPath);

    dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary
}

NSNumber *newNumberOfCompletedLevels = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];

[dict setObject:newNumberOfCompletedLevels forKey:@"gameProgress"];

NSLog(@"writing to %@…", plistPath);

[dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];


NSLog(@"dictionary values are…:");

for (id key in dict)
{

    NSLog(@"key=%@, value=%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error is in `dict` object. You have not initialized it.

Please use this line of code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

instead of:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
```

It'll resolve your issue. Please let me know your feedback.

Comment: some times this is  also a reason.

Comment: thanks for your reply but nothing is inserted into plist file

Comment: Check this to insert value in dict.      NSString *newNumberOfCompletedLevels = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d",1];

    [dict setObject:newNumberOfCompletedLevels forKey:@"gameProgress"];

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `dict` object.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```